# Typeahead messes up my CSS when i attach it

Tags: jquery, html, css, typeahead.js

i seem to have a problem with the Typeahead autocomplete library.

I have a text input field which i attach Typeahead functionality to on focus event.

The problem is as follows: as soon as the event triggers, the input bar's width becomes smaller. I've checked, and Typeahead wraps the input element in a span with the following rules:

`<span class="twitter-typeahead" style="position: relative; display: inline-block;">`

I cannot understand how any of those can mess up the width of the field.

Adding a `width:100%` rule to the `twitter-typeahead` class kinda solves it if the input is the child of an element of the same size, but that is not a feasible solution.

Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: maybe use a definite width value?

Comment: could you provide a http://jsfiddle.net so we can play with your code to discover potential issues